# Is the belief in God different to gambling with the truth?

Tags: epistemology, theology

As far as I can tell, belief in God is gambling with the truth due to the following thought process.

Axiom (1): Existence is defined by interaction.

Axiom (2): A statement of truth can be modulated into a question and answer.

Axiom (3): A scientific experiment is the physical manifestation of a question. The results are reality's answer.

Axiom (4): Observations require interaction.

Theorem (1): Any statement of truth about reality must comprise of the information obtained from an experiment, otherwise the statement is a reflection of the human mind and not reality.

Axiom (5): Gambling is a game of chance.

Axiom (6):  “Belief” is thinking something is true without evidence and the absence of a contradiction.

Theorem (2): The utilization of probability as to what is/will be/ or was true, even if the probability of being true is merely by lack of contradiction in the now, is a component of gambling. Thus belief is a form of gambling with the truth.

Axiom (7): Belief in God, is believing the statement “God Exists” to be true.

Conclusion: 
The utilization of belief with respect to the statement “God exists” is gambling with the truth. The nature of what is believed is a reflection of the human mind and not reality.

In an attempt to contradict myself, I'm struggling to think of some axioms by which I can QED the following hypothesis "Belief in God is not Gambling with the truth". Which led me to asking the following question.

In what way is the belief in God different to gambling with the truth?

To clarify possibly vague words I have used the following definitions:

By "belief", I mean thinking something is true without evidence.

By "gambling", I mean the utilisation of probability and/or lack of   contradiction, to say what was/is/will be true.

By "true" I mean a statement which can be modulated into a question and answer, where the answer is derived from experimental fact and complete absence of assumptions and can be expressed as a mathematical law.

Comment: "logical-positivism" ???

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE. Could you share a bit more of context here? How did you come to this question and what are your thoughts about it? This helps answerers to know what to write to properly answer your question. Also, as a new user, please have a look at our [tour]. Cheers!

Comment: Can someone highlight how the question is still unclear.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you would think they are the same or similar? We don't really have probabilities for the existence of something transcendental.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "belief in God" refers simply to the adoption of a set of assumptions involving a "God", whereas "gambling with the truth" is a statement involving a system, relative to a definition of "truth", which is another system.

The first refers to a description of a single structure, the second refers to the relationship between two structures.

Answer (score -2):

The believer or the atheist doesn't know certainly what truth is, they simply assume that truth is what they think. So they both are doing a gamble. So in this sense they are gambling with truth.